# System of differential equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve these system of differential equation, and I don't know how to begin. If anyone has an Idea that I can try, or know how to do, please let me know :)

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& - \sinh^2(x)\sin(y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& \ \sinh(x)\cosh(x)\cos(y)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: from where Comes this System?

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{dy}=-\tan(y)\tanh(x)$$ separate variables and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** At some points of phase plane you have that trajectory can be written not only in parametric form as $(\tilde{x}(t), \tilde{y}(t))$, but as a graph $(x, \hat{y}(x))$. To obtain differential equation for $\hat{y}$ just divide $\frac{dy}{dt}$ by $\frac{dx}{dt}$:

$$ \frac{d\hat{y}}{dx} = -\frac{\cot(\hat{y})}{ \tanh(x) }. $$

It's a first order separable equation. Could you proceed from here?

Comment: Sorry if I'm been stupid rs It's because I don't know many things about ODE, but know that I have the answer y(x), what I really want is (x(t),y(t)). Do you think it's possible?

Comment: It's okay! After you have solved this equation, you can replace $y$ for $\hat{y}(x)$ in equation for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and obtain solution $x(t)$ :)